# How to check for duplicates before saving?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, duplicates

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to add entities like this to my db.

```
public class ThingWithListings
{
    public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings;
}

public class Listing
{
    public int Id;

    public virtual ListingData Data { get; set; } // has a FK to ListingData
    public DateTime Creation { get; set; }
}

public class ListingData
{
   public int listing_id; // PK

   ....
}
```

I'm retrieving a 'ThingWithLIstings' from another source and writing it to my db. The tricky part is that any number of Listings may report to the same ListingData. So when I add or update a ThingWithListings, I need to see if a ListingData already exists and if so, just use that one.

I'm new to EF, so I've been using the AddOrUpdate from Author Vickers' article [here](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/05/03/the-key-to-addorupdate/): Obviously, this doesn't work for this scenario and so I've tried for a day or so to figure out the right way to do this. I'll spare you all the story of my main failed attempts and hope someone can just tell me the right way to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will more than likely have to query the whole table to check every value to see if there is a duplicate. If there is a better way than that, I would like to hear it.

Comment: So, the `listing_id`s from the bulk incoming data might or might not be already in the ListingData table. Is that right?

Comment: Have you got a `listing_id` (confusing name, by the way) in `Listing`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DatabaseContext.ListingData.Any(l => l.listing_id == myId)) 
{   
  //already exists 
}
else 
{   
  //do whatever 
}
```

Comment: Alex, yes, the listing_id may already be in the table. I can detect that the item already exists, no problem. But then what? I'm having trouble assinging the existing ListingData to the Listing object before adding it. I tried adding the Listing object and then marking the Listing.ListingData as unchanged. It doesn't seem like it can possibly be that hard, so I figured I must be missing the simple.

Comment: In the future, please add a description to your post and not just code.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArrivals = new ThingWithListings();
newArrivals.Listings = new List<Listing>();
newArrivals.Listings.Add(
    new Listing()
    {
        creation = DateTime.Now,
        ListingData = new ListingData()
        {
            listing_id = 1
        }
    });

//another Listing with the same ListingData listing_id
newArrivals.Listings.Add(
    new Listing()
    {
        creation = DateTime.Now,
        ListingData = new ListingData()
        {
            listing_id = 1
        }
    });

//dummy id generator
int counter = 1;
using (var ctx = new Database1Entities())
{
    //get the ListingData from the current db context
    var dbListingData = ctx.ListingData;

    // the new arrivals
    foreach (Listing item in newArrivals.Listings)
    {
        //get the listing_id of a new arrival's ListingData
        int id = item.ListingData.listing_id;

        //get the ListingData from the db, if it exists
        var listingDataFromDb = dbListingData.FirstOrDefault(i => i.listing_id == id);

        //if not, create it and add it to the db
        if (listingDataFromDb == null)
        {
            listingDataFromDb = new ListingData()
                {
                    //use the new arrival's listing_id
                    listing_id = item.ListingData.listing_id
                };
            ctx.ListingData.Add(listingDataFromDb);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        //add the Listing by using the listingDataFromDb, which now references the db ListingData
        ctx.Listing.Add(new Listing()
        {
            id = counter++,
            creation = item.creation,
            ListingData = listingDataFromDb
        });
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that besides the `Data` object reference you also have the primitive foreign key field `listing_id` in your Listing class. If not, I recommend adding it.

You could start by fetching the existing `listing_id`s in a list or array. That saves numerous database round trips later.

Then the process is really simple: for each `Listing` object that arrives check whether its `listing_id` occurs in the pre-fetched list:

- If so, do nothing with `ListingData` - just add (or update) the `Listing`, including the `listing_id` property.
- If not, add the `Listing` and set `Listing.Data` with the `ListingData` object, both as new (Added) objects. EF will set the keys.

(Note that this assumes that there are no concurrent users modifying ListingData, so it is safe to take a snapshot of the Id's)